# Uninstalling Xamarin on Windows

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, updates, uninstallation, reinstall

I want to remove previous Xamarin from my machine and install a new version (Xamarin Visual Studio 3.9.236), But when I try to install the new version I'm getting this error:

> The older version of Xamarin cannot be removed. Contact your technical
>   support group.

Any Idea?

PS: I went through [this article](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/installation/uninstalling_xamarin/#Uninstalling_Xamarin_on_Windows) but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out where the problem was! 
First I enabled msi logging for the MSI installer file:

```
msiexec /i Xamarin.VisualStudio_3.9.289.msi /l*v c:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\xamarin-vs-msi.log
```

And searched for **Return Value 3** (The Action failed):

```
MSI (s) (F8:64) [08:31:41:884]: Unexpected or missing value (name: 'PackageName', value: '') in key 'HKLM\Software\Classes\Installer\Products\371D35B64B9A7994980A677C62256FDE\SourceList'
```

As you can see the problem is a entry key in my registry I deleted it then MSI installer successfully installed:

```
'HKLM\Software\Classes\Installer\Products\371D35B64B9A7994980A677C62256FDE\SourceList'
```

Answer (score -4):

Try keyword search on the disk C "Xamarin", "Mono". And remove manually

Comment: It is probably the worse answer as it corrupts MSI installation.

Comment: If some one do this, whole installation MSI corrupt and then may be the person need to reinstall his window